# Почему не используется индекс для order by?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

У меня есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `player_statistics` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `player_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `statistic_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `value` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `statistic_player_value` (`statistic_id`, `player_id`, `value`)
)
```

Как видно, имеется индекс `statistic_player_value`, который содержит в себе 3 колонки: `statistic_id`, `player_id`, `value`.

Я тестирую индекс таким запросом:

```
explain SELECT *
FROM `player_statistics` 
WHERE `statistic_id`=1 AND `player_id` =15
ORDER BY `value` desc
LIMIT 10;
```

Результат:

```
+------+-------------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table             | type | possible_keys                                 | key                    | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | player_statistics | ref  | player_id,statistic_id,statistic_player_value | statistic_player_value | 8       | const,const |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Как видно, `key_len` равен 8, а это значит, что индекс не использовался полностью. Только `player_id` и `statistic_id` использовали индекс. Я ожидаю, что `key_len` должен быть равен 12.

Например, такой запрос выдает `key_len` 12:

```
explain SELECT *
FROM `player_statistics` 
WHERE `statistic_id`=1 AND player_id =15 AND `value` = 1
```

Так в чем проблема, почему order by тогда не использует индекс?

Comment: В индексе для столбца value используется прямая сортировка - ASC. Скорее всего поэтому он не может быть использован в запросе с обратной сортировкой. Попробуйте для начала убрать DESC из запроса и проверить план исполнения. Если индекс будет использоваться целиком, тогда можно его пересоздать указав DESC для столбца value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас срабатывает **составной индекс**, так как используете в запросе `WHERE` с указанием полей

**key_len** даёт понять используется ли он весь или только какая-то часть

Так как у вас **поля INTEGER**, которым выделена **память 4 байта** в базе, и в WHERE вы используется два поля, то в вашем запросе получается 8 при фильтрации по двум полям.

Либо 4 байта - по одному полю.

**!!** Потому что была произведена фильтрация и мы видим, что использовалось не 12 байтов, а 8 байтов в вашем случае.

Составной индекс может содержать более одного столбца и до 16 столбцов, но их общая длина ограничена 900 байтами.

- [об индексах на хабре](https://habr.com/en/post/247373/)
- [о выделенных байтах для типов полей](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html)
- [об explain](https://habr.com/en/post/211022/)

Оптимизатор запросов MySQL пытается придумать оптимальный план выполнения этого запроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Даю подробности:**
Предистория для скриншотов ниже:

*USING WHERE — не означает, что индекс не используется. Это означает,
что результат дополнительно проверяется на соблюдение условий. Наличие
индекса при вытаскивании данных можно увидеть в столбце key.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ситуация с единичными полями:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** Почему складывается ощющение, что не работает INDEX при ORDER BY?
**ОТВЕТ**
[dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html#order-by-diagnostic-information)

Искать на странице строку `ORDER BY Execution Plan Information Available`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отвечаю кратко и заранее:
Не встретили в Extra column текста Using filesort - значит всё ОК!
Если не используется индекc - увидите Using filesort

- Если заполнено possible_keys и/или как минимум key, а также в Extra нет Using filesort и нет Using temporary, то значит индекс сработал.

**Проверка на работу индексов:** удалите индекс и сделайте тот же запрос с EXPLAIN и если rows станет на порядок больше, значит до этого индексы работали.

Часть инфы может не выводится с EXPLAIN из-за версии sql, или тип базы данных, или используемых запросов + сам решает оптимизатор, что показать, а что нет

Comment: благодарю за развернутый ответ. однако почему фильтрация препятствует использованию индекса в order by? в этой статье https://ruhighload.com/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8B+%D0%B2+mysql приведены примеры, где индекс используют where + order by вместе, для быстрого поиска: "Составные индексы также можно использовать, если выполняется сортировка"

Comment: и тут тоже составной индекс используется для where + order by https://ruhighload.com/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%3F

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук, для того чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа используйте кнопку голосования

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук дополнил ответ свой текстом, ссылкой и скриншотом. После скриншотов ответил на вопрос по ORDER BY

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbyer.png это меня запутало. во первых, почему в этом случае индекс вообще использовался, ведь player_id не первая колонка в индексе. во вторых, почему key_len 12, ведь там только одна колонка player_id в условии, значит key_len должен быть 4

Comment: единственную разницу, которую я вижу, так это "Using index" в Extra, если добавить колонку `value` в индекс. если `value` в индексе не будет, то Extra будет пустым, а key_len так же будет равен 8 без изменений

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук я ориентируюсь так: ```если заполнено possible_keys и/или как минимум key```, а также ```в Extra нет Using filesort и нет Using temporary```, то значит **индекс сработал**. Если всё таки преследует паранойя, то ```удалите индекс и сделайте тот же запрос с EXPLAIN и если rows станет на порядок больше, значит до этого индексы работали```. Часть инфы может не выводится для анализа из-за версии sql, тип базы данных, запросов + сам решает оптимизатор, что показать, а что нет в таблицы результата с командой EXPLAIN SELECT

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения. раньше я думал, что надо смотреть на key_len, а оказывается все сложнее. без `value` в индексе запрос выполняется медленнее, т.к. индекс используется